# Content of the website goes beside the toolbar instead of below

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to follow a tutorial on YouTube to create a toolbar, but I am using Vuejs instead of regular HTML like on the video and the content of the views (.vue files) goes beside the toolbar instead of below it and another thing, I try to make center the toolbar.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="toolbar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href>Our Team</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href>Camp Sites</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href>Mission &amp; Vision</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href>Resources</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Things to do</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href>Activities</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href>Parks</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href>Shops</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href>Events</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href>Map</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href>Directions</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">News</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <router-view/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```css
#app {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  background-size: none;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.toolbar ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: arial;
}

.toolbar ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.toolbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.toolbar ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.toolbar ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

.toolbar ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

Whatever what I tried today, either the view was correctly below the toolbar but then the submenus were unclickable, or the views were below and centered but with a big margin-top to make the menu clickable or just beside the toolbar.

I am trying to replicate this kind of toolbar with the views right below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is 'float'. You will need a div with clear:both style after the toolbar and before the div containing router-view.

...

div class="toolbar"

...

/div

div style="clear:both"/

div

router-view

...

Comment: Thanks, it works!  I guess I learnt something new today!  
Do you know how I could make the toolbar centered?